# How to tell on the server-side if user has JavaScript disabled

Tags: javascript, html, apache, post

I have an Apache Server with a database and a homepage that executes a JS script to send static data back to the db. I want to send to the server whether the user has JS disabled, but since it's disabled, the script won't run. What should I use to do this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Comment: You could put an element into the HTML that loads a resource from the server, and have JavaScript remove it. So if the server receives the request for that resource, it knows that JS was disabled. I'm not sure how feasible this is, since the request might be sent immediately on loading the element's HTML, and removing it won't prevent that.

Comment: You could send an AJAX request from the JS. If the server doesn't receive the request within some time of the page being sent, it means JS is disabled.